# How to uninstall vscode?

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall

Stupid question, I know, but I just can't figure out how to remove VSCode from my Ubuntu 20.04.

I don't remember how I downloaded and installed it, and `history` doesn't go that far back.

I know it's installed, because if I press the super key and enter "vscode", it shows up:

[image]

However,

```
$ sudo apt remove vscode
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package vscode
```

Hm. Maybe I downloaded it as a `.deb` and installed it with `dpkg`? However, `dpkg --list` gives me

```
ii  vnstat
ii  wamerican
```

with nothing in between, so no vscode entry. I've also tried with the Ubuntu Software Center, but that only gives me the option to install it, so it obviously doesn't know it's already installed.

So I'm at an impasse. How do I remove this thing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you installed it via `apt`, then it’ll be:

```
sudo apt remove code
```

If it was via the Snap Store, then:

```
sudo snap remove code
```